# How to use a table with integer column names?

Tags: sql, r, kdb

I've been playing around with my work's kdb time series database. Usually I just interface to it from our R libraries. I noticed that the q-sql syntax sugar https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/ does not seem to work with columns that are integers. Are there any work arounds, such as adding the letter "c" to all the column names other than my "Date" column?

For example:

Consider the table `` t:([]c1:`a`b`c`a;c2:20 15 10 20;c3:99.5 99.45 99.42 99.4) ``.

Rename the first column to `1`: `` t: `1 xcol t ``.

Now both `select 1 from t` and `` select `1 from t `` fail!

Does anyone have any workarounds/hacks/fixes to this problem?

Comment: what do you mean, you paste ``t:([]c1:`a`b`c`a;c2:20 15 10 20;c3:99.5 99.45 99.42 99.4)`` in the q console and then you will have the table `t` in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to name columns `1`, `2` etc. you can use [functional forms](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/) of `select`, `exec`, `update` and `delete` or you can use [.Q.id](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qid-sanitize) a.k.a. sanitise to do the job for you:

```
    q)t:([]c1:`a`b`c`a;c2:20 15 10 20;c3:99.5 99.45 99.42 99.4)
    q)t: `1 xcol t
    q).Q.id t
    a1 c2 c3
    -----------
    a  20 99.5
    b  15 99.45
    c  10 99.42
    a  20 99.4
    q)select a1 from .Q.id t
    a1
    --
    a
    b
    c
    a
```

Comment: Awesome .Q.id makes my life so much easier (I can refer to integer columns with a1, a2, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is bad practice to rename columns as numbers as it can be difficult for kdb to interpret. However a work around is functional form of the select:

```
q)?[t;();0b;(enlist `1)!enlist `1]
1
-
a
b
c
a
```

More details on functional qsql here: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/